# Why importing operator in RxJs is needed?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

While following an Angular tutorial, I found this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.heroService.getHero(+params.get('id')))
      .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }
}
```

Sorry if I found this a bit strange (due to 2 reasons: I came from Java and I'm not really following latest JS technology). Isn't `switchMap` a method owned by `param map` which an `Observable<ParamMap>`? When I remove the import statement, the code doesn't compile.

I use RxJava, but all methods required to manipulate an observable are already there (attached) with the Observable class itself.

Can someone tell me, why `switchMap` import is required? Possibly, give me some reference links.

Comment: As RxJs is functional, I don't see why `paramMap` would "own" `switchMap`.

Comment: Check the example usage in their docs https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs.

Comment: What I understand in object oriented programming, if an object is followed by dot (.), then something with curl for e.g. `rectangle.calcArea()`, then the `calcArea` function should be defined as a function/method in the `rectangle`.

Comment: because loading all rxjs library is really big (it will be inefficient, the rendering of the page will be slow). So it preferable to import only what you need, in your example you need **switchMap** so you just need to import the **switchMap** function (not all functions of rxjs). In Java you don't need to care about it, the entire library is imported into your project.

Comment: @sancho21 right, but without the import that method doesn't exist. The import adds that method.

Comment: So, I wonder how the import can add `switchMap` functionality (method/function) to the observable? I don't get the logic. Is this a new functionality in Javascript? Could you give me some links to read further about this technique?

Comment: Within the .Net world exists already the same mechanism. There it is called *extension method*. It creates a static function which first argument is an instance of the desired class. But in code you use this method as it would be a member method of the target class.

Comment: I guess the imported script contains statements to add a function to the class. It's like modifying the prototype of `Observable` class. If this is the case, it's not a new technique. But, it is indeed smart!

Comment: @sancho21 it's most definitely modifying the prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read this article : [Where are my Observable operators](https://manuel-rauber.com/2016/01/04/where-are-my-observable-operators/)

at lot of operators are missing. But this is not a fault, this is by design. Angular will not ship all available operators. This would result in additional 300 kb. So, to get an Observable with more operators, you could either import the ones you need, or import all.

when you build web application you should use less http requests,
and for better performance you should compress your file size.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you understand if you dig into the source files in your `node_modules` folder. When you import `switchMap` your typescript loads `switchMap.d.ts` but the compiled javascript loads `switchMap.js`.

`switchMap.d.ts` has a declaration for `interface Observable<T>`, but when you define an interface with the same name as an existing one, typescript will merge the two interface definitions. So all the import does at compile time is make the new `switchMap` method accessible to anything using an `Observable`:

```
import { switchMap } from '../../operator/switchMap';
declare module '../../Observable' {
    interface Observable<T> {
        switchMap: typeof switchMap;
    }
}
```

The javascript file on the other hand modifies the `prototype` for the `Observable` class. This adds the new method into all instances of `Observable`, so without loading this javascript the method simply doesn't exist:

```
"use strict";
var Observable_1 = require('../../Observable');
var switchMap_1 = require('../../operator/switchMap');
Observable_1.Observable.prototype.switchMap = switchMap_1.switchMap;
//# sourceMappingURL=switchMap.js.map
```

Of course you don't have to import `switchMap` directly for it to be present, if any code in your program imports it then the `switchMap` method will exist at runtime, but if you don't have the `import` typescript will try to prevent you using it.